# Combine multiple automation result reports into one

Tags: visual-studio, automation, coded-ui-tests, extentreports

**What I want to achieve**
I'm running CodedUI automation scripts in a distributed mode across multiple physical machines. I'm using ExtentReports to generate a results.html after the execution of tests. My goal is to have one results.html after execution of tests.

**What I've achieved**
Currently I am able to execute my automation tests fine on machine which will correctly generate a results.html with all the test that were run. Great! :)

**My current problem**
Now as soon as I use Visual Studio's Controller/Agent model to distribute tests to multiple physical machines I run into a problem. That problem is that each machine will create its own results.html file for the tests that ran on that particular machine.

My idea to resolve this problem was to write the results file from each physical machine to a shared drive location and specifying the "append existing" parameter when declaring a new ExtentReport instance to true.

All machines will successfully write to this location but the problem is only the test from the last machine that completed it's tests will be appended to the results.html.

I would like to know if what I'm trying to achieve is possible and whether anyone else has had any problems with combining reports from distributed environments/how they achieved it?

Thanks 
Tim

Comment: <a href='http://klov.herokuapp.com/projects'>Klov</a> server is probably what you need in this scenario.  However, to answer the original question, it would be good to know how are you distributing your tests?  If you are using a grid->hub for example, you should still get a single report as tests are distributed across the right nodes.